# Boolean parameter in function creates error?

Tags: php

My code shoot out an error when i execute.

```
function give_me_title(array $var,boolean $condition){
    if($condition){

        return $var['title'];
    }
    else{
        return 'la condition n\'est pas remplie';
    }
}
$published = false;
print 'Le titre est :'. give_me_title($article,$published);
```

the error message

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to give_me_title()

If i remove the keyword 'boolean' and i precise the parameter $condition as like follow

```
function give_me_title(array $var,$condition=null)
```

the error message is gone. What is the reason? php function doesn't accept boolean parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `boolan`.

Next thing is that `boolean` keyword does not exist for this context and you cannot use it to define the type of argument.

Correct way is:

```
function give_me_title(array $var, $condition) {
  $condition = (bool) $condition;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typehinting for scalar values are not supported in PHP.

You can only typehint classes, interfaces, arrays or callables

[phpdocumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)